# How to properly use JQuery load() function?

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, html

I have hit a dead-end here. I am trying to reload a dropdown menu using the JQuery load() function in my ajax function and I can't seem to get it right. The problem is basically with the CSS styling and the Javascript.

Let's say I make an ajax call that adds a user to my database and want to display that user in a drop-down menu on the same page using the `load` function. I tried a way that works, it properly updates the drop-down but then my page style breaks in the sense that it loses all the styles from my `styles.css` file which is loaded from the `<head>`. Now I have searched around for a few solutions but I can't find much about it except for the fact that it's one of the drawbacks of Ajax.

I can't figure out what would be a proper way to solve that problem. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Here's a snippet of my code:

**PHP/HTML**

```
<!-- PHP codes up here which has my DB config, initiated the PDO, some html, etc -->
<div id='checkoutProcedure'>                        
    <!-- Some divs here which are unrelated to the problem -->

    <div id='clients'>
        <form id="clientSelect" name="clientSelect" method="post" action="">
         <span class="plain-select">

            <select name="select_client" id = "select_client">
              <option value="Select Client" selected>Select Client</option>
              <?php
              $sql3 = "SELECT `a`, `b`, `c` FROM `table` ORDER BY `a` ASC;";
              $stmt3 = $con->prepare($sql3);
                  $stmt3->execute();   

                while($row = $stmt3->fetch())
                {
                    if(isset($_POST['client']) && $_POST['client'] == $row[1])
                    {
                        echo '<option selected="selected" id="user_id-{$row[0]}" value="' . utf8_encode($row[2]) . '">' . utf8_encode($row[2]) . '</option>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<option id="user_id-{$row[0]}" value="' . utf8_encode($row[2]) . '">' . utf8_encode($row[2]) . '</option>';
                    }
                }
              ?>
            </select>
              </span>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Ajax load() snippet**

```
success:function(response){
    $('#checkoutProcedure').load('user.php #checkoutProcedure');
}
```

Comment: move `checkoutProcedure` outside of the file so it's a containing wrapper. You're getting nested ID's with this method.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I'm not sure I follow what you mean here. Could you please enlighten me? :) Edit okay, I get what you mean. Let me try

Comment: You are including `<div id="checkoutProcedure"` twice. Once on page load and then again on `.load()`. It will then appear twice in the code. Move it outside of the user file.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Okay, I get what you mean, but when you say move it out of the file, where do you move it to? I apologize if this question sounds a bit stupid but I'm really not having a clue here.

Comment: I assume you do something like `include user.php` in your template file. instead you should do `<div id="checkoutProcedure"> <?php include 'user.php'; ?></div>`. This way it's not in the ajax call you make to load the target element.

Comment: Ohh no no. user.php contains the php snippet in the OP

Comment: So `user.php` just contains the results you get back? Then you need to change your selector so it puts the `<options>` in the `<select>`, Something like this: `$('#checkoutProcedure select').load('user.php);`

Comment: Okay, makes sense. It now works (i.e loads) but the problem is the dropdown simply becomes empty. So upon inspecting my `select` element, I see that the whole page is re-written in the select, i.e everything from the `<title>` tag to my `<footer>` tag. Is that how it's supposed to be? Can't we just reload the select and display the data? I am guessing loading everything into the `select` breaks it down internally and not visually to the point it doesn't work(becomes a blank dropdown)

Comment: See, then your `user.php` file isn't just the php code, it's more than that. You need to chain the selector off of it. `.load("user.php #checkoutProcedure select")`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy but the it doesn't load again. This is so crazy I feel my mind is going to explode.

Comment: `.load()` is a shorthand version of an Ajax request so use one or the other. Try $`(#checkoutProcedure).html(response)` instead

Comment: @Ohgodwhy `response` echoes something else which is not the data for the dropdown. But I guess you unblocked me. I might actually use the html and get a JSON response which would simply fetch the dropdown data. I can't see another way to reload that dropdown just using load, nothing seems to work